# ¿Cómo contar el total de productos en la unión de tablas?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Tengo la siguiente consulta, en la tabla productos (tbl_products) la estoy enlazado por el id de la tienda (id_store), lo que necesito es contar cuantos productos publicados tiene la tienda en la tabla (tbl_products), intente lo siguiente pero no me cuenta.

```
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT st.id_store,
                            st.photo,
                            st.store,
                            st.address,
                            st.phone,
                            st.email,
                            st.in_offer,
                            st.url,
                            COUNT(p.id_product) //p.id_store
                        FROM tbl_store st
                        LEFT JOIN tbl_products p ON st.id_store = p.id_store
                        WHERE st.id_user=?");
$stmt->bind_param("i",$id_user);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result(
    $st_id_store,
    $st_photo,
    $st_store,
    $st_address,
    $st_phone,
    $st_email,
    $st_in_offer,
    $st_url
);
$stmt->fetch();
```

Comment: @Josbert No entiendo como sería, pero lo que si de la tabla productos específicamente solo necesito contar el total de productos que tiene la tienda

Comment: ¿Estás trayendo solo a un **usuario/tienda** o a una lista de ellos?

Comment: @Josbert Solo un usuario el que inicia sesión en el sistema, de ese usuario que tiene una tienda mostrar el total de productos que tiene publicados. En la tabla productos no tiene id del usuario sino el id de la tienda, en la tienda si esta el id del usuario.

Comment: Te daré una respuesta para ello dame unos minutos

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Bien continuando lo que te decía en los comentarios, te lo explicare en esta respuesta un poco mejor.

Para traer el conteo de todos los **productos** que tiene una **tienda** puedes hacer una pequeña [**subquery**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/subqueries.html) desde la tabla **tbl_store** hacia la tabla **tbl_products**

De la siguiente manera:

```php
$stmt = $con->prepare("SELECT photo, store, address, phone, email, in_offer, url, 
   (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM `tbl_products` WHERE `tbl_store`.`id_store` = `tbl_products`.`id_store`) AS total
   FROM `tbl_store` WHERE `id_user` = ? LIMIT 1");

/* 
 * Acá el resto de tu codigo, una vez hecha la consulta
 * ...
 */
```

Lo que he hecho acá es traerme un dato personalizado desde una **subquery** *(Consulta que está dentro de `()` los paréntesis)*, trayendo el conteo de sus filas en la tabla relacionada **tbl_products**